# SKEmitterNode disappears when added to a new SKScene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene, skemitternode

I have a `SKEmitterNode` that's running on a `SKScene` and I want to move it to the next `SKScene` without interrupting the particles.

Normally I'd do it like the following:

```
let scene: SKScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
let transition = SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 0.5)
self.view!.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
```

And then on the next SKScene:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    particleEmitter.removeFromParent()
    addChild(particleEmitter)
}
```

This works perfectly fine however in this situation I don't want to use a transition when moving to the next SKScene. I've tried it without a transition like:

```
let scene: SKScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
self.view!.presentScene(scene)
```

And the `SKEmitterNode` disappears as soon as the new `SKScene` is presented even though I've removed it from the last `SKScene` and added it as child to the new one.

My question is why is the `SKEmitterNode` dissapearing and how can I get it to work without using a transition between the SKScene's. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Note: Using a `SKTransition` with a duration of 0 also works but this causes a noticeable 'flash' during the transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be any flashes and such. If I understand you correctly, what you need to do is to create an emitter in a global scope. Before presenting the next scene,  you should remove the emitter from its parent. When you are in the next scene, you add emitter to it. I just tried and it works for me without any lag, flashes or something.

Here is the code...There are two scenes...A `GameScene`:

```
import SpriteKit

let emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Fireflies")

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        backgroundColor = .black

        if let emitterNode = emitter {

             addChild(emitterNode)
        }
         print("Game Scene")

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if let scene = WelcomeScene(fileNamed: "WelcomeScene") {

            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            emitter?.removeFromParent()

            self.view?.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
}
```

and a `WelcomeScene`:

```
import SpriteKit

class WelcomeScene:SKScene{

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        backgroundColor = .black
         print("Welcome Scene")
        if let emitterNode = emitter {
            addChild(emitterNode)

        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {

            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            emitter?.removeFromParent()
            self.view?.presentScene(scene)
        }

    }
}
```

For the emitter I've used standard fireflies template.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is exactly what I tried to do originally and it wasn't working for me. That being said I just tried it again (literally just uncommented the original code) and it's suddenly working fine... I'll mark this as correct, thanks.

Comment: @jm1175 Maybe something else was the cause of lag. You know, initialization of sprites with textures and such. Anyways, glad to hear it worked for you! :) Happy coding.